# Nuxt.js is not importing font-face properly

Tags: sass, fonts, nuxt.js

I'm using custom font files with Nuxt project. I tried to add font files to /static/fonts and import them using

```
  font-family: 'coconregular';
  src: url('fonts/cocon-regular-font.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('fonts/cocon-regular-font.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;

}

$cocon: 'coconregular';

.brand-name {
  font-family: $cocon;
}
```

I'm having    '@nuxtjs/style-resources' installed and all other variables and SCSS loading is working totally fine but fonts are not loading.

This is my file structure
[files screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SyNK.png)

I can't find a way to add fonts properly neither i don't know how to check if the font is loaded. There aren't any errors.

What is the correct way for Nuxt and SCSS to load fontfiles?

Answer (score 3):

So i finally figured out good workaround. I don't know if this is good or not, but i separated fonts download from anything else.  Therefore i added another entrypoint to nuxt.config.js to include fonts stylesheet before other stuff.

```
css: [
    '@/assets/scss/theme/fonts/stylesheet.css',
    '@/assets/scss/main.scss'
  ],
```

It worked good because My fonts stylesheet for Woff and Woff2 files were generated by font squirrel generator anyway.

Hope this helps you guys